# Angular directive binding without template controllerAs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, angular-template

I'm encoutering an issue when using a custom directive without template (use Server generated DOM) and binding my view to a controller.

Here is my jsFiddle sample :

```js
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .directive('myDirective', function(){
     return {
          bindToController: true,
          controller: 'myController',
           controllerAs: 'ctrl',
           scope: {
             text: '@'
           },
         }
    })
    .controller('myController', function($scope){
      this.text = $scope.text
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="myModule" data-my-directive='' data-text="Hello world!">
  <h1>
    {{ ctrl.text }}
  </h1>
</div>
```

The same sample using a string template for my directive or a template url will works but I need to used the server DOM.

Does anyone had got the same issue and resolved it ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directive will compile only `template/templateUrl` present in directive with directive scope. Otherwise inner content of directive would get the scope, where that html have been placed.